# Redirect all request to index.php file in public folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am facing issue while redirecting all request to index.php file which is placed in public folder.

```
Name_of_app
|-app
|  |--controllers/
|-config/
|  |--db.config
|-public/
|  |--js/
|  |--css/
|  |--index.php
|  |--.htaccess
|-vendor/
|-.htaccess
|-composer.json
```

There are two .htaccess files , 
First is  Name_of_app/.htaccess file , this should redirect all traffic to Name_of_app/public folder

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Second is Name_of_app/public/.htaccess file that redirects all traffic to /public/index.php file

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Issues are:
1. I can't access /public/index.php file from url www.name_of_app.com/ .
2. www.name_of_app.com/index.php shows /public/index.php page not found error

Help me in resolving this issue.Thanks .

Comment: Why would you want to split that rule set into two separate files? That only makes things more complex and further slows down the http server. Integrate the rules.

Comment: With that directory structure I'd set the `DOCROOT` to being the `public` folder to be honest.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "I can't access"? _Be precise_. "shows ... page not found error" means what _exactly_? _Where is that error shown?

Comment: @arkascha url www.name _of_app/   shows   "The requested URL /public/ was not found on this server."

Comment: Sorry, but I actually doubt that. This would mean that details of the internal rewriting process are exposed to the outside which does not sound likely. I have the impression that your real world issue actually looks different to what you post here.

Comment: @arkascha please let me know , what should be done to redirect all of the request to index.php file in public folder. This is what my main motive is .

Answer (score 2):

Delete `/public/.htaccess`. In `/.htaccess` put this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!public/(?:index\.php)?$) public/index.php [L]
```

Your PHP app should then parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to see the URL as it was sent. Use any query within it to overwrite the contents of `$_GET`, then regenerate `$_REQUEST` from `$_GET` then `$_POST`. An easy way is like so:

```
$url_path = explode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?', 2);
if (isset($url_path[1])) {
    parse_str($url_path[1], $_GET);
}
else {
    $_GET = [];
}
$url_path = (string) substr($url_path[0], 1);// ignore leading '/'
```

You may not need `RewriteBase`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for Name_of_app/public/.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "The requested URL /public/ was not found on this server." error while accessing localhost/name_of_app/

Comment: What kind of results when used in this way, for Name_of_app/.htaccess

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/index.php$1 [L]`